# gotoAndPlay(label) stop all other actions on the page

Tags: actionscript-3

I am actually at UNI doing bachelor of multimedia and we are creating a Flash movie for an assignment.

In all my fixing up, I have wrecked some code and I can't see why it won't work, because it is exactly the same as in the file that does work.

I have several buttons on one page that when clicked just go to other pages, they are working fine with functions. I have some buttons that go to a name label at a certain frame, it works for the first button, then it seems that once that button is clicked, it some all other functions on the page and no other buttons can be clicked.

Here is the code:

```
phonebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, goPhone);

function goPhone(evt:Event):void{
    gotoAndStop("phone");
}

emailbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, goEmail);

function goEmail(evt:Event):void{
    gotoAndStop("email");
}

addressbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, goAddress);

function goAddress(evt:Event):void{
    gotoAndStop("address");
}
```

If I put in `gotoAndPlay()`, it plays too long and goes to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed one mistake in your function statement . that

```
function goEmail(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("email");
}
```

you need to write MouseEvent whenever you are writing event for Mouse. and this is not an issue. try this. And gotoAndStop will stop on that frame. If there is any frames under that particular target frames or  movieclip it will play that only not on currentTarget frames. So without seeing your frames code it is little difficult to identify your problem because you have asked on frames code. I hopes it wuld help*